# How can I save press keys to a variable use pygame.key.get_pressed()?

Tags: python, pygame

I want the buttons on the keyboard to be saved in a variable. Then I plan to use them for printing. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

`pygame.key.get_pressed()` returns a list with True or False for each key at specific indexes. If you would like to create a list with the names of the keys being pressed you could loop and get their names as so:

```
keys = [pygame.key.name(index) for index, press in enumerate(pygame.key.get_pressed()) if press]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write something like:

`pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()`

if you want to get a specific key, you would write:

`pressed[pygame.K_key]`

but replace 'key' with the name of the key. The list of names is on the [pygame docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html). This statement will be true if the key is pressed, otherwise it will be false.